# Excel using Index for large number of rows

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

```
=INDEX(Analysis!F2:F99999, SMALL(IF($B$1=Analysis!$A$2:$A$99999,ROW(Analysis!A2:$A$99999)-ROW(Analysis!A2)+1),ROW(1:1)))
```

I am trying to use the formula above to find all rows with a specific  phone number. The formula then returns the record specified to he sheet. This formula will not work with sheets that contain a lot of data does anyone know why and how can I fix the issue?

Comment: It is an array formula and the calculations are exponential.  So at some point it will crash excel.  At this moment the best solution will be vba.

Comment: cant you simply filter the range? or add a helper-column (which simply returns the row-number if it matches with your $B$1... then you can easily go with just INDEX and SMALL (and no array formulas would be needed)